# Public link to Alfresco document using CMIS integration

Tags: java, playframework, alfresco, opencmis

I'm integrating a Java BackEnd with Alfresco repository using OpenCMIS. I have everything working ok, I can create documents, folders, versioning documents, etc.

The problem is that I need to provide a public link to that document to my frontend (iOS and Android app).

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Public link as in "I don't need to authenticate to open it"?

Comment: yes, no autentication required.

Comment: That looks like a security breach. Anyone having the link will access your documents. Please use some kind of authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure about CMIS, I've given up on it a long time ago. But the feature itself does exist. https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/shared-links